# Mapping 2 object and create object based on values

Tags: javascript

I have an object that is build with from an html form. 
When i fill the form I obtain this json object we call "jsonObjectForm" :

```
{
  "inputID1": "content1",
  "inputID2": "content2",
  "inputID3": "content3",
  "beginningDate": "2020-02-02",
  "endingDate": "2022-03-03",
  "inputID4": "content4",
  "inputID5": "content5",
  "inputID6": "content6",
  "inputID7": "content7",
  "inputID8": "content8"
}
```

I have a second object that i have to use to build a sql query. this object is

```
let fieldNames = {
    "inputID1": "dbField1",
    "inputID2": "dbField2",
    "inputID3": "dbField3",
    "inputID4": "dbField4",
    "inputID5": "dbField5",
    "inputID6": "dbField6",
    "inputID7": "dbField7",
    "inputID8": "dbField7",
};
```

I found the way to browse the first object. I defined the form elements i want to "scan" in the form :

```
const pageFormElements = getAllFormElements(document.getElementById("requestForm"));

for(let [key, value] of Object.entries(jsonObjectForm)) {
    pageFormElements.forEach(element => {
        console.log("key: " + key + " | value: " + value);
    }
}
```

My question is how do i manage the double forEach in this case and I wonder if there's a way to "map" the values from the first object to the second and build a final object that would look like this:

```
let fieldNames = {
    "dbField1": "content1",
    "dbField2": "content2",
    "dbField3": "content3",
    "dbField4": "content4",
    "dbField5": "content5",
    "dbField6": "content6",
    "dbField7": "content7",
    "dbField7": "content8",
};
```

My objective is to create a query like this

```
query = select * from whatever where dbField1 = content1 AND dbField2 = content2 ... AND dbField8 = content8;
```

Comment: do you have empty values? what happens with numbers? or substrings?

Comment: Yes i can have empty values. And the second object do not include the date that are managed separatelly...

Comment: why not change the input fields of the form dircty to the names of the database field names?

Comment: I can try this way but i don't think it will be appreciated ...

Comment: what should happen with the date? which field is associated to it?

Comment: I append it to a specific part of the request ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate the fields and assemble the wanted query by having a look to keys with `beginning` and `ending` prefix for `BETWEEN` expressions.

```js
var data = { inputID1: "content1", inputID2: "content2", inputID3: "content3", beginningDate: "2020-02-02", endingDate: "2022-03-03", inputID4: "content4", inputID5: "content5", inputID6: "content6", inputID7: "content7", inputID8: "content8" },
    fields = { Date: 'date', inputID1: "dbField1", inputID2: "dbField2", inputID3: "dbField3", inputID4: "dbField4", inputID5: "dbField5", inputID6: "dbField6", inputID7: "dbField7", inputID8: "dbField7" },
    result = Object
        .entries(fields)
        .map(([k, v]) => (('beginning' + k) in data) && (('ending' + k) in data)
            ? `${v} BETWEEN '${data['beginning' + k]}' AND '${data['ending' + k]}'`
            : `${v}='${data[k]}'`
        )
        .join(' AND ');

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: this works perfectly thanks ! i should be able from there to manage the "undefined" when field is not set..

Comment: You could filter first before mapping, or take `flatMap` and insert an empty array.

Comment: I used a regex and replace what i want to remove :) i'll have a look at flatmap ! thanks

Comment: here is the regex i used : (?:[a-zA-Z0-9_]+='undefined' <[/]And>)

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```js
const content = {
  "inputID1": "content1",
  "inputID2": "content2",
  "inputID3": "content3",
  "beginningDate": "2020-02-02",
  "endingDate": "2022-03-03",
  "inputID4": "content4",
  "inputID5": "content5",
  "inputID6": "content6",
  "inputID7": "content7",
  "inputID8": "content8"
}

const fieldNames = {
  "inputID1": "dbField1",
  "inputID2": "dbField2",
  "inputID3": "dbField3",
  "inputID4": "dbField4",
  "inputID5": "dbField5",
  "inputID6": "dbField6",
  "inputID7": "dbField7",
  "inputID8": "dbField7",
};

const result = Object.entries(fieldNames).reduce((a, [k, v]) => (a[v] = content[k], a), {});

console.log(result);
```

This will go through `fieldNames` entries and generate a new object using the entry's value as key and as value, the value from the `content` object that matches the entry's key.

Answer (score 1):

This code can do it for you:

```js
const content = {
  "inputID1": "content1",
  "inputID2": "content2",
  "inputID3": "content3",
  "beginningDate": "2020-02-02",
  "endingDate": "2022-03-03",
  "inputID4": "content4",
  "inputID5": "content5",
  "inputID6": "content6",
  "inputID7": "content7",
  "inputID8": "content8"
}

const fieldNames = {
  "inputID1": "dbField1",
  "inputID2": "dbField2",
  "inputID3": "dbField3",
  "inputID4": "dbField4",
  "inputID5": "dbField5",
  "inputID6": "dbField6",
  "inputID7": "dbField7",
  "inputID8": "dbField7",
};
const result = {};
Object.keys(fieldNames).forEach(key => result[fieldNames[key]] = content[key]);
console.log(result);
```